# Fluentd. Why aren't custom logs delivered to Elasticsearch (EFK)?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluent, fluentd, efk

For testing, I created a file in my `home` directory:

```
touch /home/testuser/test.log
```

I use `td-agent` to deliver logs to Elasticsearch (EFK).

This is my test configuration in `td-agent.conf`:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/testuser/test.log
  read_from_head true
  tag test.**
  <parse>
    @type none
  </parse>
</source>

<filter *.**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    hostname "#{Socket.gethostname}"
  </record>
</filter>

<match test.**>
  @type elasticsearch
  host .....
  port .....
  user .....
  password .....
  logstash_format true
  logstash_prefix test
  flush_interval 1s
</match>
```

Then I started the agent. There are no errors in the agent's logs. It is written that the agent monitors the specified file.

After that, I started filling in the log:

```sh
echo "123" >> test.log
echo "456" >> test.log
echo "789" >> test.log
```

No new entries have appeared in the `td-agent` logs. In `Kibana`, the index "test- *" does not appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For debugging purposes, it's better to use `stdout` output plugin before sending logs out to ElasticSearch. According to the documentation of [`read_from_head`](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#read_from_head), "When this is `true`, `in_tail` tries to read a file during startup phase. If target file is large, it takes long time and starting other plugins isn't executed until reading file is finished." I guess that your file is empty on start, right? Otherwise, you'd see its content on startup.

Comment: Relevant: https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#in_tail-doesnt-start-to-read-the-log-file-why

Comment: I tried to specify a small, non-empty file - nothing appeared either. Also tried specifying a 2 megabyte `catalina.out` file from Tomcat - also without result.

Comment: Could you please try with a minimal configuration? For example, tail a file that grows every second and its output on stdout. I believe there's a similar question asked recently. Click on flientd tag and you'll see the questions.

Comment: Output to stdout with td-agent?

Comment: Yes. Just to verify that `tail` works and it forwards logs to filter and then they are routed to stdout. You'll be sure that this part is working fine. Then, you can proceed with ElasticSearch.

Comment: Are you using kubernetes container and keeping the logs?

Comment: @Azeem i'm trying stdout:  
`<match test.**>`
  `@type stdout`
`</match>`                 
In log all good:       
2020-08-09 13:06:15 +0400 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=178463 ppid=178460 worker=0
2020-08-09 13:06:15 +0400 [info]: #0 following tail of /home/nahimov/test.log
2020-08-09 13:06:15.298175189 +0400 test.home.nahimov.test.log: {"message":"123","hostname":"nahimov-laptop"}
2020-08-09 13:06:15.298187063 +0400 test.home.nahimov.test.log: {"message":"456","hostname":"nahimov-laptop"}

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov: Are you seeing logs now? The log file `/home/testuser/test.log` is empty at startup or are there any logs in it? Did you test with `read_from_head false` and manually pushing logs to it using `echo` command or some other way? Did you try with a test file other than this one?

Comment: @AnuragJain no. Native `td-agent` and flie in hoast system

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov: As per your edited comment, the logs are coming up, right?

Comment: @Azeem I found problem! It is parameter `logstash_format true`. If I remove this parameter, then the contents of the `test.log` file are passed to Elasticsearch. But in this case the `logstash_prefix test` parameter does not work, the index has the name `fluentd` and it does not look like, for example, the syslog index in Kibana: `system-2020.08.08`

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov: Good going! I believe that you're looking for [`index_name`](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/elasticsearch#index_name-optional).

Comment: @Azeem Yes! It's work! Thanks!

Comment: @AlexeyNakhimov: Awesome! :) And, welcome! You might want to post an answer for this to help others facing a similar issue. Cheers!